# Passing two parameters to a named query

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejbql

I have the following namedquery over my entity "Intervention ":

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "Intervention.findNextMission", query = " SELECT i FROM Intervention  i       WHERE i.heureDebut> :DateToBeSpecified and i.idAgent= :idAgent")`
```

i dont know how to call this query in my code by passing two parameters : date,id. Normally it should be like this :

```
List <Intervention> ListOfInterventions = em.createNamedQuery("Intervention.findNextMission").setParameter().getResultList();
```

what to put between the parentheses of setParameter() ??

here follow the code of my entity Intervention :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "intervention")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Intervention.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM Intervention i"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Intervention.findByIdIntervention", query = "SELECT i FROM Intervention i WHERE i.idIntervention = :idIntervention"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Intervention.findByHeureDebut", query = "SELECT i FROM Intervention i WHERE i.heureDebut = :heureDebut"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Intervention.findByHeureFin", query = "SELECT i FROM Intervention i WHERE i.heureFin = :heureFin"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Intervention.findNextMission", query = " SELECT i FROM Intervention i WHERE i.heureDebut> :DateToBeSpecified and i.idAgent= :idAgent")})
public class Intervention implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "IdIntervention", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String idIntervention;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HeureDebut", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date heureDebut;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HeureFin", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date heureFin;
    @Lob
    @Size(max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "NotesGeneral", length = 65535)
    private String notesGeneral;
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdValidation", referencedColumnName = "IdValidation", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tablevalidation idValidation;
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdNatureIntervention", referencedColumnName =  "IdNatureIntervention", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Tablenatureintervention idNatureIntervention;
    @JoinColumn(name = "IdAgent", referencedColumnName = "IdAgent", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Agent idAgent;
    @JoinColumn(name = "RefContrat", referencedColumnName = "RefContrat", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Projet refContrat;

    public Intervention() {
    }
    //getters and setters 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setParameter` accepts either `(int position,Object value)` or  `(String parameterName,Object value)`. So your code could look as:

```
Date aDate=....
Long anId=....   
List ListOfInterventions = em.createNamedQuery("Intervention.findNextMission")
  .setParameter("DateToBeSpecified",aDate,avax.persistence.TemporalType,DATE)
  .setParameter("idAgent",anId).getResultList();
```

Note that when you use a `Date` you should specify the `TemporalType` intended.

Comment: Hi Carlo i've tried this but it's not working, it's throwing the following exception : javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter idAgent with expected type of class MajanTelepointage.entities.Agent from query string  SELECT i FROM Intervention i WHERE i.heureDebut> :DateToBeSpecified and i.idAgent= :idAgent.

Comment: Sorry, I've not dug in your `Intervention` object.  `Intervention.idAgent` is actually an `Agent` instance, so  I suggest that you modify the query to refer the id on the `Agent` type as in ` ... i.idAgent.idAgent=:idAgent ... ` (assuming that `Agent.idAgent` is a String)